# Is it true that if there exists a surjective function $f:E \to \mathbb{N}$, then $E$ is at most countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $E$ be a set. If there exists a surjective function $f:E \to \mathbb{N}$, then $E$ is at most countable.

In here, $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of natural numbers. I have to prove this statement. But I have no idea what to do first. Help me.

Comment: Suppose it isn't ! What then ?

Comment: Is $f$ injective?

Comment: Should I find a contradiction??

Comment: No. Just surjection

Comment: @user138163 If $f$ is injective, then $E$ is by definition countable.

Comment: The first edit removed the fact that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: @user138163: Could the question say "at least countable"? Of maybe $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow E$? As posed, the statement is false.

Comment: Aha! I got it. It's a false statement. I should find a counterexample. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I guess I'll delete my comment now since it gives away the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is surjective, then $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\exists e\in E$ such that $f(e)=n$. However, by the definition of surjection, $f$ may map more than one element of $E$ to the same element of $\mathbb{N}$, thus allowing us to conclude that $E$ may be *at least countable* - it need not be countable. As a counterexample, consider some $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{N}$. Make up one of your own. Go have some fun!

Comment: The quantifiers in your answer says that the function is constant?  Instead, what you want to say is if $f$ is surjective, then $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\exists e\in E$ such that $f(e) = n$.  But everything else is fine.  Basically, after that fix, you know that the map $f$ may take more than one element of $E$ to the same element of $N$, only allowing us to conclude $E$ must be at least countable, but need not be countable at all.

Comment: @NicholasStull See my edited answer.

Comment: Yep.  Just noticed that.  +1 of course.